# How to specify server IP for a HTTP request instead of DNS

Tags: ios, networking, dns, nsurlconnection, sni

***What I want***:

Specify server IP for NSMutableURLRequest to avoid localDNS query.

***Common method***:

Replace host field in URL and specify the HOST Header field for the HTTP request.

```
request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://1.1.1.1/path"]];
[request setValue:@"www.a.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"host"];
```

***Problem***:

If my server serves several domains, then the server will return a default certificate for my request. SNI only works when it finds host in url.

So any suggestion if I wanna achieve ***What I want*** in ***Problem*** scene.

Comment: if you want to serve a page at HTTPS://12.34.56.78 then you need a certificate for 12.34.56.78 the host header simply needs to match what is in on the certificate

Comment: @MichaelB-AzureMVP I wanna serve a page at https://www.a.com/path but I has to specify the IP (Assume I know it in advance) for www.a.com at the client side instead of DNS. How can I deal with this situation.

Comment: Did you solved the problem? I have the same question, but i do not find a solution yet. Can you give me a favor?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Host header is used for determining the certificate.  The server never sees the complete URL.  IIRC, NSURLSession and friends don't normally override a user-specified Host header if the URL contains an IP address.  However, it should be a capital "H" in "Host".  Because that header *is* in the list of headers that you aren't supposed to touch, the capitalization may matter.

If fixing the capitalization doesn't work, there are a couple of other approaches you could consider:

- Add the hostname in a different header field, then use a custom authentication handling delegate method to explicitly validate the cert against that cert's domain yourself, and if it validates **and** it is one of your certs **and** it is for one of your domains, allow the request to continue even if the cert's domain doesn't match the request's domain.
- Include a rudimentary proxy in your app, and configure the session to always use it when connecting to that host by name.  In the proxy, open up a normal TCP/IP NSStream to the correct IP address and pass data back and forth.
- Write a custom HTTPS client that supports just enough functionality to handle whatever you're doing.